# how convert oct number into decimal number with R's sprintf?

Tags: r

I can convert between hex number  and  decimal number ,convert decimal number into oct number ,how can i conver oct number into decimal number with sprintf function in R?

```
sprintf("%x",255)
[1] "ff"
sprintf("%d",0xff)
[1] "255"
sprintf("%o",255)
[1] "377"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `strtoi()`:

```
> strtoi(20, base=8)
[1] 16
```

You can then `sprintf()` away...